# Python's Decimal type not Real?

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from numbers import Number, Complex, Real

z = Decimal(0)

# Expected: a == b == c == True
# Actual (Python 3.6.5):
a = isinstance(z, Number)  # True
b = isinstance(z, Complex) # False
c = isinstance(z, Real)    # False
```

`Decimal` appears to implement everything that is needed to be considered `Real` according to [PEP3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/), so what gives? Notably, `fractions.Fraction` is correctly categorized by the above snippet (e.g. `a == b == c == True`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually mentioned in [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/#the-decimal-type):

> After consultation with its authors it has been decided that the Decimal type should not at this time be made part of the numeric tower.

So `Decimal` was intentionally excluded.

Comment: That teaches me to read to the end!

Comment: @Jason In looking for why, I found another question here that goes into more detail, so you should check that out as well.

Comment: thanks for finding that -- the posted solution is both obvious and exactly what I needed, and the explanation is also very informative and likely to save me from seemingly random errors in the future.